# How do I deform an object smoothly?

Tags: modeling

I am very, very new to blender and just learning how to deform. However, I am unable to figure out how to deform a pre-existing obj.

To describe what I mean,
There is a deflated balloon/semi-circle hanging under a flat plane. In the original obj, the plane and the balloon/circle are considered separate parts. Now what I'm trying to do is to push the balloon so that it inverts/flips. So far, selecting vertices and pulling makes it look awful. I tried to hook as well, but it does not deform nicely.
Is there a way I can make the obj behave less 'rigid'? Maybe consider that the balloon is a cloth and deform as I pull it?

[image]

This is only a rough example, but what I aim to do is by pulling the top of the sphere down, the rest of the semi-circle will deform to follow it, instead of just the edges

Comment: An image or a file could help ;)

Comment: try proportional editing: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional%20editing

Comment: I've made a very rough model and I hope the point in conveyed. However, unlike the picture, they are both a single obj though they have been divided into different sections